# Error al importar MySQL; "No module named 'MySQLdb"

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, python-import

Estoy intentando conectarme desde Python 3.4 a una base de datos que tengo en MySQL, he intentado varias formas sin resultados, he instalado varios paquetes y módulos y nada, ¿qué estaré haciendo mal?

Este es el error que me sale luego de que pongo `import Mysqldb`

```
 import MySQLdb
```

> ```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):   
>     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>  ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
> ```

Comment: Hola Laura ¿Has instalado [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) en ese intérprete sin errores previamente?

Comment: en realidad no es error de conexion , es error de importacion te hace falta el modulo en python

Comment: Para aclarar, **MySQL-python no está soportado en Python 3, para usar MySQLdb en Python 3 se debe usar su fork  mysqlclient**. El import es correcto, el error solo muestra como comenta JackNavaRow que el módulo no se puede importar, o no has instalado mysqlclient correctamente, o lo has instalado en otro intérprete que tengas en el sistema... Para poder ayudar hace falta más información al respecto (Módulos que has instalado, cómo lo has instalado, posibles errores durante la instalación, comprobación de que está usando el mismo interprete en el que has instalado para ejecutar el script, etc.)

Comment: te coloco el modulo que te hablo FJSevilla , [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Answer (score 0):

EN Python 3 MySQLdb no está soportado, eso se usó en Python2. Para realizar las conexiones en Python3 puedes emplear la librería mysqlclient en su lugar.

Para instalar ejecuta el comando

```
pip install mysqlclient
```